# Rails 5: Query for empty association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models `Client` and `MealWeek` and I want to be able to pull all clients **without** any **active** meal weeks.  I can pull active meal weeks by doing either of the following:

```
Client.find(x).meal_weeks.where(active: true)
Client.find(x).meal_weeks.unused
```

I can easily pull clients **with** active meal weeks:

```
Client.includes(:meal_weeks).where(meal_weeks: { active: true })
```

But the same cannot be said for clients without active meal weeks.  I've tried including a `not` in the query above but that returns all clients with **inactive** meal weeks, not client's without any active meal weeks (**all** meal_weeks are `active: false`).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't get your question, sorry. Aren't `clients with inactive...` the same as `clients without any active...` ?

Comment: `Client.includes(:meal_weeks).where.not(meal_weeks: { active: true })` This will find Clients where any meal_weeks is false rather than where they are all false. Hopefully, that makes sense :)

Comment: @fanta I want what @Gabbar is stating.  I want to find clients where all their meal_weeks are `active: false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails 5+ you can use `where.not` So in this case, your query would be

```
Client.where.not(id: 
  Client.select(:id).joins(:meal_weeks)
      .where(meal_weeks: {active: true})
)
```

This will use a sub query of your original version as a NOT IN clause. Resulting SQL

```
SELECT 
 clients.* 
FROM 
 clients
WHERE 
 clients.id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT 
     clients.id
    FROM 
     clients
      INNER JOIN meal_weeks ON meal_weeks.client_id=clients.id
    WHERE 
      meal_weeks.active= true
  )
```

Comment: I've never thought to find it like this!  Very clever